# How to fix undefined variable when my route is slash using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Hellow developers, I have problem on my controller, when i tried to accessing the slash route i got this error get_the_recent_post (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\staging_project\resources\views\index.blade.php) that error happens when my account is log off. however if my account is logged in there is no error found.

To understand well, if i access this link **http://localhost:8000/** and my account is off i got this error **Undefined variable: get_the_recent_post,** however if i access my account the data that i fetch in database is showing.

**Goal: if my route is http://localhost:8000/  my output must be same as on http://localhost:8000/index**

**My Route:**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
  return view('/index');
});

Route::get('/index', 'HomeController@index')->name('index');
```

**HomeController:**

```
   /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    // public function __construct()
    // {
    //     $this->middleware('auth');
    // }
/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
 */

public function index()
{

    $get_the_recent_post = DB::select('SELECT content_id,content_title,content_desc,when_created,content_author FROM icweb_content WHERE content_status = ? AND MONTH(when_created) = MONTH(CURDATE()) ORDER BY when_created DESC LIMIT 3',[

        'Approved'

    ]);

    $get_the_upcoming_event = DB::select('SELECT ic_content.content_id,content_title,content_desc,content_author,start_event,end_event,when_created FROM icweb_content as ic_content 

        WHERE content_status = ? AND  start_event = CURDATE() AND end_event >= CURDATE() ORDER BY when_created DESC LIMIT 3
        ',[

            'Approved'

        ]);

    return view('/index')
    ->with('get_the_recent_post',$get_the_recent_post)
    ->with('get_the_upcoming_event',$get_the_upcoming_event);

}
```

**index.blade.php:**

```
    @foreach($get_the_recent_post as $data_recent_post)
        <a href="" style="text-decoration: none;">
          <div style="line-height: 2px;">
            <h5 class="card-title" style="font-weight: 500; font-size:13px;  color:black;">{{$data_recent_post->content_title}}</h5>
            <p class="card-text" style="color:#757a91; font-size:12px; font-weight: 500;">{{strip_tags($data_recent_post->content_desc)}} </p>
          </div>
        </a>
   @endforeach
```

Comment: I think you need to call "HomeController@index" in your "/" route also.Same as it is you have called in "/index" route.

Comment: @SohilChamadia i tried that but still not work

Comment: In your '/' action you are just loading the view page with out data you need to load the data too

Comment: or else you need to do like this Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('index2');

Comment: When you call "HomeController@index" in your "/" route then what issue you are facing?

Comment: This page isn’t working "HomeController@index" in your "/"

Comment: your suggestion same, this page isn;t working

Comment: Then need to debug the code where the issue is.Can you please share the code of controller and route file?

Comment: Hi @SohilChamadia it works now, but  when i try to put that. my redirect is in login. if the user is not authenticated. how to make if not authenticated it will go to the route of backslash.?

Comment: You have used auth command of laravel for login functionality?

Comment: my controller has problem, i solved my problem. thanks for suggestion guys. i will post the correct answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Change your route and then hit.

Example:- `Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');`

If This one is not working then need to debugging.

Comment: if i try to put that, happen page not responding

Comment: Hi Amir khan when i try to put that. my redirect is in login. if the user is not authenticated. how to make if not authenticated it will go to the route of backslash.?

Comment: Use dd('check'); for check the function is calling or not. if page not respond it may be a query problem.

Comment: @SoulAiker If you went to redirect without login a user than please write your route outside the Auth Middleware and check isset on blade file  if(isset($get_the_recent_post)){ foreach(....) { ----- } } else { }

Answer (score 0):

**To solved my problem:**

I comment out this function

```
// public function __construct()
// {
//     $this->middleware('auth');
// }
```

Comment: Okay so this is the auth middleware of laravel.So if you wan't to not access any of the controller to the user before login then you need to use this.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your route like the code snippet shared below.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
  return redirect()->route('index');
});
```